# migrate from mysql to sql server express - concerns

Tags: mysql, sql-server-express, database-migration, msde

I have a desktop application which is distributable commercially. Currently I use MySQL as database but I read I need commercial license for MySQL each sale of my software.

So I am planning to move to SQL server express or MSDE as it is freely distributable. 
now why I am thinking about both msde and express is it says MSDE has a workload governor which has impact on performance. but express doesnt have it. Database size of 10 GB would be fine for me. 1 GB ram should be fine hopefully. but I'm a bit concerned about performance.

So would MSDE still be a choice? Would it be available in 2012 and further on?

A query in Express would be as fast as SQL server enterprise?

Is there any other factors I should consider ?

Comment: depending on how your application connects to mysql, you may not need commercial licensing: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/02/17/when-are-you-required-to-have-a-commercial-mysql-license/

Comment: hello. thanks for the reply. but could you elaborate a little?. for eg. if my cd contains Mysql setup ,my software setup and mysql connector setup and i just install those and use it then do i not need a license?. here it says otherwise. http://doc.ctrlaltdel.ch/database/mysql/manual_Licensing_and_Support.html#User_adding_MySQL. Sorry i m a bit confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDE has been long discontinued, and SQL Server Express is a replacement for it.

I would be very surprised if SQL Server Express performance was inadequate for a desktop application, although who knows, maybe your workload has some special requirements? The best approach to be sure is to hook it up and give it some test workload and measure.

Comment: thank u. I did not test the performace yet. but because it says it is a scaled down version of sqlserver i was wondering if it would have impact on performance of say executing a query also. also how much would be the impact of the workload monitor in sql server which is not available in express. if it affects only for hundreds of concurrent connections then it s OK for me.

Comment: I would read it this way: It is scaled down from the full SQL Server that is meant to run on big iron and handle millions of transactions per second. It should be able to handle a desktop app :-)